# Copy List with Random Pointer C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve this interview problem in C++ on leetcode, and here is my code, and I write my own test cases to verify the solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

 struct RandomListNode {
   int label;
   RandomListNode *next, *random;
   RandomListNode(int x) : label(x), next(NULL), random(NULL) {}
 };
RandomListNode *copyRandomList(RandomListNode *head);
void printList(RandomListNode* head);

int main()
{
    RandomListNode* list1=new RandomListNode(1);
    RandomListNode* list2=new RandomListNode(2);
    RandomListNode* list3=new RandomListNode(3);
    RandomListNode* list4=new RandomListNode(4);
    RandomListNode* list5=new RandomListNode(5);
    list1->next=list2;
    list2->next=list3;
    list3->next=list4;
    list4->next=list5;
    list1->random=list3;
    list3->random=list5;
    list2->random=list1;
    list4->random=list3;
    RandomListNode *copied=copyRandomList(list1);
    printList(list1);
    cout<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void printList(RandomListNode* head)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<head->label<<" "<<head->random->label<<endl;
        head=head->next;
    }
}

RandomListNode *copyRandomList(RandomListNode *head) 
    {
        RandomListNode *p=head;
        p=p->next;
        RandomListNode *q=new RandomListNode(p->label);
        RandomListNode *q1=q;
        unordered_map<RandomListNode*, RandomListNode*> hashMap;
        hashMap.insert(make_pair(head, q));
        // deep copy the list with all the next pointers
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            RandomListNode *tmp=new RandomListNode(p->label);
            q->next=tmp;
            q=q->next;
            hashMap.insert(p,q);
            p=p->next;
        }
        p=head;
        q=q1;
        // deep copy the random pointers
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            if(p->random!=NULL)
                q->random=hashMap[p->random];
            p=p->next;
            q=q->next;
        }
        q=q1;
    }
```

However, when I tried to compile, there is an error saying:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Hash<_Traits>::insert(std::pair &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'RandomListNode' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xhash    684

Comment: Did you try to specify the type when calling make pair e.g: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/insert/

Comment: @clancer the problem is the call to insert *without* make_pair. See Mike's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`insert` takes a single argument, a key-value pair, not two separate ones for the key and the value. So

```
hashMap.insert(p,q);
```

should be

```
hashMap.insert(make_pair(p, q));
```

just like you did a few lines before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code I wrote today for the same question on LeetCode, it took 108ms, I solved the solution in 1 pass and no additional data structures are used.

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list with a random pointer.
 * struct RandomListNode {
 *     int label;
 *     RandomListNode *next, *random;
 *     RandomListNode(int x) : label(x), next(NULL), random(NULL) {}
 * };
 */

class Solution {
public:
RandomListNode *copyRandomList(RandomListNode *head) {
    RandomListNode* cur=NULL;
    RandomListNode* nhead=NULL;
    if(!head)
        return NULL;
    cur=new RandomListNode(head->label);
    nhead=cur;
    while(head){
        if(head->next)
            cur->next=new RandomListNode(head->next->label);
        if(head->random){  
            if(head->random==head->next)
               cur->random=cur->next;
            else
                cur->random=new RandomListNode(head->random->label);
        }
        head=head->next;
        cur=cur->next;
    }
    return nhead;

}
};
```